# Spring data redis support for modules?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, redisjson

I'm using Spring data Redis (version 2.1.1RELEASE) with the driver of lettuce (version 5.1.3RELEASE)
I want to use this module: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/ but the driver doesn't seem to support it.

I tried use the `execute` method:

```
Object response = redisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<String>) connection -> {
  return  (String) connection.execute("JSON.GET foo");
});
```

And got an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandType.JSON.GET FOO

Is there a way to do that? How can I utilize Redis modules?

Comment: did you manage to overcome it?

Comment: @GuyKorland I did, but it required some infra work, I'll post the solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I managed to do it like that:

First extend `ProtocolKeyword` and replace all '_' chars with '.':

```
public interface ModuleCommand extends ProtocolKeyword {

  @Override
  default byte[] getBytes() {
    return name().replaceAll("_", ".").getBytes(LettuceCharsets.ASCII);
  }
}
```

Second, create an enum with the types of commands you wish to implement:

```
public enum JsonCommand implements ModuleCommand {

  JSON_GET,
  JSON_MGET,
  JSON_SET,
  JSON_ARRAPPEND,
  JSON_DEL,
  // other commands you wish to implement
  ;
}
```

Now here's the interesting part, I already integrated more modules so I has to generalize the execution part:

```
public abstract class ModuleAbstractManager {


  protected ByteArrayCodec codec = ByteArrayCodec.INSTANCE;

  @Autowired
  private LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  protected <T> Optional<T> execute(String key, ModuleCommand jsonCommand, CommandOutput<byte[], byte[], T> output, String... args) {

    List<byte[]> extraArgs = Arrays.stream(args)
        .filter(arg -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(arg))
        .map(String::getBytes)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CommandArgs<byte[], byte[]> commandArgs = new CommandArgs<>(codec)
        .addKey(key.getBytes())
        .addValues(extraArgs);

    LettuceConnection connection = (LettuceConnection) connectionFactory.getConnection();

    try {
      RedisFuture<T> future = connection.getNativeConnection().dispatch(jsonCommand, output, commandArgs);
      return Optional.ofNullable(future.get());
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
    finally {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the execution itself:

```
@Service
public class RedisJsonManager extends ModuleAbstractManager {

  public static final String ROOT_PATH = ".";
  public static final String OK_RESPONSE = "OK";
  public static final String SET_IF_NOT_EXIST_FLAG = "NX";


  public Optional<String> getValue(String key) {
    return getValue(key, ROOT_PATH);
  }

  public Optional<String> getValue(String key, String path) {

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    return execute(key, JsonCommand.JSON_GET, new ValueOutput<>(codec), path)
        .map(String::new);
  }

  public Optional<String> getValue(String key, List<String> multiPath) {

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(multiPath)) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    String[] args = multiPath.toArray(new String[0]);
    return execute(key, JsonCommand.JSON_GET, new ValueOutput<>(codec), args)
        .map(String::new);
  }

  public boolean setValueIfNotExist(String key, String json) {
    return setValue(key, json, ROOT_PATH, true);
  }

  public boolean setValueIfNotExist(String key, String json, String path) {
    return setValue(key, json, path, true);
  }

  public boolean setValue(String key, String json) {
    return setValue(key, json, ROOT_PATH, false);
  }

  public boolean setValue(String key, String json, String path) {
    return setValue(key, json, path, false);
  }

  private boolean setValue(String key, String json, String path, boolean setIfNotExist) {
    return execute(key, JsonCommand.JSON_SET, new StatusOutput<>(codec), path, json, setIfNotExist ? SET_IF_NOT_EXIST_FLAG : "")
        .map(OK_RESPONSE::equals)
        .orElse(false);
  }

  public Long addToArray(String key, String json) {
    return addToArray(key, json, ROOT_PATH);
  }

  public Long addToArray(String key, String json, String path) {
    return execute(key, JsonCommand.JSON_ARRAPPEND, new IntegerOutput<>(codec), path, json).orElse(0L);
  }

  public Long delete(String key) {
    return delete(key, ROOT_PATH);
  }

  public Long delete(String key, String path) {
    return execute(key, JsonCommand.JSON_DEL, new IntegerOutput<>(codec), path).orElse(0L);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current Spring data Redis (version 3.1.4) it is possible to execute custom commands `template.execute((RedisCallback<byte[]>) c -> (byte[]) c.execute("JSON.GET", key.getBytes()))`

Complete example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisCallback;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

    private final StringRedisTemplate template;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public <O> Optional<O> getObject(String key, Class<O> valueClass) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(template.execute((RedisCallback<byte[]>) c -> (byte[]) c.execute("JSON.GET", key.getBytes())))
            .map(v -> map(v, valueClass));
    }

    private <O> O map(byte[] value, Class<O> valueClass) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(value, valueClass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Can't deserialize the object: {}, with class {}: {}", value, valueClass, e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```